# can't open file '/c': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I just downloaded SublimeText 3, because I wanted something faster to run code than PyCharm. And every time I try to run something I get the same Error: `can't open file '/c': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

And I don't understand why it doesn't work, the problem doesn't seem to be caused by permissions, and I think that my path is setup in a good way. So here I am, I hope someone can help me.

Edit : I’m on Windows 10 and haven’t changed or created any file in SublimeText folders.

Here is the complete diagnostic SublimeText sent to me. The code I'm running just prints "Hello World". (and I don't wan't to show my name, so I replaced it by the word "User" instead) :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file '/c': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 2]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\Users\User\Documents\Python\test.py"]
[dir: D:\Users\User\Documents\Python]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin;;]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Did you create your own `sublime-build` file (say for example so you could execute Python 3)? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: So, I use Windows 10 and haven’t changed any file I haven’t added any extensions.

Comment: In that case, including the complete diagnostic output that Sublime generates in your question would be helpful; it includes the command that was executed as well as other things that might make it more clear why you're seeing this happen.

Comment: I added the complete diagnostic to the post. And I'm really wan't to thank you for helping me @OdatNurd.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see anything obviously wrong with that. It's executing the command that one would expect, and I would assume that if there's a problem with the code you're running that it would result in a Python stack trace and not what looks like an error coming from the Python interpreter itself. Conspicuously, `/c` is what Python passes to the windows shell to tell it to run a command. Is your `COMSPEC` environment variable set to point to something other than `cmd.exe`?

Comment: I'm not sure about what it really means, but after some researches I typed `%ComSpec%` in Windows executor and it opens `python.exe` insted of `cmd.exe` so i guess that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to resolve it thanks to @OdatNurd !

My `COMSPEC` environment variable was badly set up. I don't know why but mine was pointing `python.exe` and I could make it work by changing it to the path of `cmd.exe`.